# Not able to move the slider, as web driver is not able to locate the element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, slider

I'm trying locate and move the slider to different value than what is is by default. However, the web driver is either not able to locate the element or not able to perform action. Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yIK3.png)

Answer (score 0):

WebElement priceSlider  = findMyElement(d, locator, locatorvalue);
                //int val = 100/Integer.parseInt(locatorvalue);

```
            int abc=100/Integer.parseInt(testdata);

            Dimension sliderSize = priceSlider.getSize();
            double sliderWidth = sliderSize.getWidth();

            System.out.println("Slider width : " + sliderWidth);

            double ab=(sliderWidth)/abc;    
            float f = Math.round(ab);
            System.out.println("Float f : " + f);
            int valu = Math.round(f);
            System.out.println("Value of valu " + valu);
            Actions move = new Actions(d);
            move.moveToElement(priceSlider, valu, 0).click();
            move.build().perform();
            System.out.println("Slider moved");
```